# How to run nmap scripts without nmap asking admin privileges each time?

Tags: admin, privileges, nmap, winpcap

Nmap asks admin privileges each time I restart my machine(which is logged into work domain). How do I avoid nmap asking admin privileges each time I run a script? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you add an example of the command you're trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nmap only asks for privileges in order to start the Npcap packet capture driver if it is not started already. Upgrade to the latest version of Npcap to avoid bugs, and during installation make sure that you leave the "Automatically start the Npcap driver at boot time" box checked.

Future releases of Npcap will always start at boot because of [problems like this with on-demand start](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/1502).